# How-to init a ListPreference to one of its values

Tags: android

I'm trying to set a defaultValue to a ListPreference item.

Here is an sample of my preference.xml file:

```
<ListPreference android:key="notification_delay"
    android:title="@string/settings_push_delay"
    android:entries="@array/settings_push_delay_human_value"
    android:entryValues="@array/settings_push_delay_phone_value"
    android:defaultValue="????">
</ListPreference>
```

The two arrays:

```
<string-array name="settings_push_delay_human_value">
    <item>every 5 minutes</item>
    <item>every 10 minutes</item>
    <item>every 15 minutes</item>
</string-array>
<string-array
    name="settings_push_delay_phone_value">
    <item>300</item>
    <item>600</item>
    <item>900</item>
</string-array>
```

When i go into the preference activity, no item of the ListPreference is selected. I've tried to set an int value like 1 in the "android:defaultValue" fied to select "10 minutes" but it does not work.

```
<ListPreference android:key="notification_delay"
    android:title="@string/settings_push_delay"
    android:entries="@array/settings_push_delay_human_value"
    android:entryValues="@array/settings_push_delay_phone_value"
    android:defaultValue="1">
</ListPreference>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You need to specify the *value*. So to get the first entry selected by default specify `defaultValue="300"` in your example.

Comment: This works well, programmatically I have a 300 value. But in fact what I'd like is to select "graphically" one of the rows of the ListPreference by default.

Comment: In my application it does exactly that: The value specified for "defaultValue" is selected in the preferences list, when the app is started for the first time. Don't why this shouldn't work for you...

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I made an error between the default values and the values in the array. It works fine on all the phones I tried. Thanks.

Comment: Minor thing, I found cleaner to abstract the default value out into a string, then reference that.

Comment: Is it possible to specify an index in the array? like the first entry in it...?

Comment: @TomerZ if you're referring to XML, no, you have to specify the value of the first entry.

Answer (score 19):

Happened to be in same situation. Specifying a consistent default value. But graphically was not selected. I cleared the application data. And then it worked as expected.
So a clear may be useful at dev time when adding new XxxPreference items.

Comment: Same for me. I cleared the application data and everything works well!

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Sven's answer, you have to call the setDefaultValues() method in the starting activity. This will set once all default values.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Set all default values once for this application
  // This must be done in the 'Main' first activity
  PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is a valid value from the list, then re-install the app. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

(if you dont put the default value the summary will be : **Not set**

you can fix it try this :

instead of

```
android:defaultValue="1"
```

put

```
app:defaultValue="1"
```