# Default value in ListPreference from array.xml

Tags: android

I would like to set default value of ListPreference as first element of array which is declared in array.xml. I would like to do it fast and simple.

Code like this:

```
 <ListPreference
android:key="fontSize"
android:title="@string/fontSize"
android:entries="@array/fontSize"
android:entryValues="@array/fontSize[0]"/>
```

of course "@array/fontSize[0]" dosen't work, it's clear, but there's other way to do something like this in XML or in code SIMPLY?

Comment: In the last line, perhaps you meant android:defaultValue? BTW, it seems impossible to do what you want in pure XML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How-to init a ListPreference to one of its values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770100/how-to-init-a-listpreference-to-one-of-its-values)